# CMake 3.5.0 Verbose mode for a Dummie

Tags: cmake, clion

What’s up everyone!

I’m very new to CMake and unfortunately have to go knee-deep into it blind. I'm running windows 10, CMake 3.5.0, CLion IDE.

The software developer demands for the verbose output log, but I can't figure this one out.

I’ve put `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` line to CMakeLists.txt to enable the Verbose mode.
src:  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html

But I can't figure out where the hell I'm supposed to be getting the output.

I know you CMake gurus will be like LOL, but it is a hard ball for me yet, hopefully not for too long.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362176/clion-and-cmake-messages ?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/09/clion-opens-2016-3-eap/#cmake_output

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your CLion IDE window you should see various tabs such as Messages and CMake.
Clicking on Messages will give you the console for build output, and clicking on CMake should give you the console for CMake's configure output. See screenshot below:

[image]